# Mulesoft - Uh-oh spaghettios! There's nothing here

Tags: rest, mule, cloudhub

This error is driving me nuts...

Situation:
I am trying to create a REST api and use a api-gateway proxy to access it. Proxy URL is HTTPS.
The deployment goes through fine. No errors reported in the logs. Worker assigned.
However when I try to access through browser get the "Uh-oh spaghettios! There's nothing here.".
Have tried all the usual things like making the https port dynamic using ${https.port} and using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost in the http-listener config. But that does not help. Has this something to got to do with the proxy version ?

Any help or pointers will be great!

Comment: You definitely need to configure ${https.port} on your HTTP listener if HTTPS.
Are you able to access the REST API without the api-gateway proxy? My understanding is the Proxy URL is the one not accessible.

Comment: Yes. Thats the first thing I checked. The application is accessible and works without the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow Steps 2 from below link
[Getting Started with Connectors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/getting-started-with-connectors)

Answer (score 0):

All,
Got the resolution. The problem was with the certificate chain. The keystore did not contain intermediate certificates. When added to the keystore the connectivity worked fine.
Only if Mulesoft provided correct errors or detailed logging, I would have saved lot of time over this.

Thanks for your inputs.